# RemoteApp approval time

Tags: azure, remoteapp

How long takes the normal approval time for RemoteApp (I'm waiting one week!).

I want to check/test this new azure Feature for us.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, Microsoft are experiencing longer-than-normal delays currently with requests to join their preview features.  It took over a week for my request to be accepted onto the Azure Files Preview.